# Coding a calculator in python, need some assistance

Tags: python, calculator

Please help me understand what im doing wrong: trying to code a calculator.

Ive tried using debuggers. to no avail.

I keep getting indentation errors, and Im not sure what Im doing wrong. Maybe its my loops?

Tried moving things around, still not giving me any output. Can someone look at my loops and advise me?

Please help guide a young coder trying to learn!

```
    while False: 
        options = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
        choice = input('Enter choice(1/2/3/4):')
        try:
            choice = int(choice)
            if choice not in options:
                print("Invalid input.")
                break

            num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
            num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

        except:
            print("Please use one of the following(1/2/3/4): ")
            continue 
        break

    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        print_result(multiply(num1, num2))

    elif choice == 2:
        print_result(divide(num1, num2))

    elif choice == 3:
        print_result(subtract(num1, num2))

    elif choice == 4:
        print_result(add(num2, num1))

    else:
        print("Invalid input")

    while True:
        try:
            retry = str(input("Do you wish to do another calculation(y/n): "))
        except:
        if retry == 'y':
             break
        elif retry == 'n':
             break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input - Use y or n")
            continue

    if retry == 'n':
        print("Thanks for using our amazing calculator!!!")
        break

    print("Restarting...")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: `while False` will never be executed.

Comment: Also in the  last `if`   the is outside loop, Can you double check if the code that you posted is correctly formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the mistakes in your code,follow these instructions to get it right:

- Indentation has to be uniform , i.e , four spaces or a tab,use either one of those
- `while False:` will never execute , change it to `while true`
- Make sure to define all your functions like `multiply` , etc.
- try the builtin `eval()` function , but do not use for any production as it executes any python code sent to it

```
    print( eval( input("Input equation here:") ) )
```

- Write the whole calculator code in a function and use a return statement to exit every loop at once to end program like this :

```
    def myfunc():
        ...some code...
        if retry == 'n':
            return 0
        else:
            ...more code...
```

Make sure to check out [this free e-book](https://goalkicker.com)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see in your code is the first line that says `while Fasle:` it should be `while True:`

**For a loop to execute the condition must always be true.**